# How to get Rails 3 plug-ins to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out how to install a plugin in Rails 3 (probably the time it wouldve taken me to build the plugin myself). So rather than wasting more time,I'm hoping someone can simply explain how I can incorporate plugins in the vendor/plugins folder (which I've unzipped there) into an application. The installation instructions for Rails 2 are below:

Then you need to copy the configuration files, database migration and UI files into your application like so:

./script/generate install_has_threaded_comments

Comment: It looks like the has_threaded_comments gem (plugin) doesn't support rails 3.  Check out [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading) for Rails 3 threaded comments.  There's install instructions inside too.

Comment: Thanks..there's a lot of friction between material in Rails 2 and Rails 3. I really hope a new version isnt released anytime soon.

Comment: No problem.  Checkout the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) for a list of common gems and try to stick with gems that support Rails 3.

Comment: Ive never come across it before; seems like a valuable resource. I'll be sure to use it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3.2 has deprecation warnings for using vendor/plugins and advocates adding gems to your Gemfile for everything.

```
gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'
```

Rails 3 converts Rails 2's script/generate (or script/anything) to:

```
rails generate acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration
```